# Line numbers for errors no longer appear in LogCat

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

So I recently update my android studio and now I cannot see what line of code causes the app to crash I just get the error and what activity it was caused in, how do I get the actual line , please help this makes debugging my apps almost impossible[image: My debug screen]

Comment: Is this Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: I used to use AS but when I updated it messed up the line numbers. I switched to eclipse and it still doesn't show the line numbers either

Comment: I've always preferred to run logcat from the command line, and often filter it through grep...

Comment: you sir are a savior! how do I filter for runtime exceptions tho

Comment: Try [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)